# Doctrine 2: Hydrate key-value array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Why this query doesn't work?

```
    $query = $this->_em->createQuery('
        SELECT 
            COUNT(p) AS products_count
        FROM 
            Application\Entity\Category c
            INDEX BY c.id
            LEFT JOIN c.products p
        GROUP BY
            c.id
    ');

    $rows = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

I expected to get the result as: "category_id => products_count" array, but it throws an Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException without any message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `COUNT` the rows in a query that is `GROUPED`, it will return multiple results with the count for each group. In your case, you will get the counts for each `Category`.

If you try to `getSingleScalarResult()` on a result which has more than one entries, it will produce a `Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException`. Instead, you should use `getScalarResult()` and iterate through the entries.

**Edit:**

To transform the results to the form `array("category_id" => "products_count_value")`, you can use the following code:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($rows as $category, $values) {
    $output[$category] = $values['products_count'];
}
```

`$output` should now contain the values the way you want them.

Comment: So, I used wrong method for fetching data. If I use getScalarResult, the result looks like: "category_id" => array("products_count" => "products_count_value"), but I need to fetch data in the following format: "category_id" => "products_count_value", without extra iteration. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, it depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Right now you get the number of products for each category. Do you want the overall number of products? Or the number of products for a specific category?

Comment: I need to get the number of products for each category in simple format: category_id => products_count.

Comment: I don't think that's possible out of the box. However, you can transform the result to fit to your specifications. Please look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I use array_map for that. I just wanted to get confirmation that there's no out of the box solution.

Answer (score 2):

[This trait](https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/9ef4c5dcc4e2aa881240370b6f27c8f4) will give you the result in the expected format for simple entity fields. After `use`ing in your repository, you can use it like:

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Branch')->getIndexedList('id', 'name');
```

But, for your case, as it has some aggregation result, you may write a similar function in your repository.

(Though it's a very old question, posting it here so that it may give a hint to someone who will be searching for a similar idea.)

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said this is not supported by Doctrine by default. You could use PHP's [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function for this:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery('
    SELECT 
        COUNT(p) AS products_count, c.id AS category_id
    FROM 
        Application\Entity\Category c
        LEFT JOIN c.products p
    GROUP BY
        c.id
');

$pairs = array_column($query->getArrayResult(), 'products_count', 'category_id');
```