# Doctrine 2 get pairs id=>value

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Hello i have one quick question.

I'm using **Doctrine 2** and i need to get pairs from specific table as array.
For example, i have table **"Category"** with columns **('id', 'name', 'description' , ...)** and i want to get all rows in array format *(category.id=>category.name)* as follow:

```
array(
   7 => 'News',
   8 => 'Sport',
   11 => 'Work'
)
```

(I have only 3 categories with ids 7,8,11 in this example).

Is there some simple and quick way how to do it?

Comment: You can use 'Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY' if you use the builder. This will return the object as an array instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2: Hydrate key-value array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861411/doctrine-2-hydrate-key-value-array)

Answer (score 1):

I think, in that case you should write your own custom hydrator [Custom Hydration Modes](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#single-scalar-hydration)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

OR

```
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

For more Info. See [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

To convert `categoryId` to array key and `categoryName` to value

```
$newArr=[];
foreach($result as $cat){
    $newArr[] = [$cat['id'] => $cat['name']];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it returns array like array(0=> array('id' =>7, 'name' => 'News'), ... ) instead of array(7 => 'News', ...).

Answer (score 0):

Get results as array

```
$result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

You can then use a for each to modify your results as follows:

```
$modifiedResults = array();

foreach ($results as $row)
{
    array_push($modifiedResults, array($row['id'] => $row['names']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpeler than previous answers. 
You can do this by using a PDO constant and Doctrine's Database Access layer (DBAL).

From a controller :

```
$dbal = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$idsAndNames = $dbal->executeQuery('SELECT id, name FROM Categories')
                    ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

This will result in the array from your question.

Comment: You are assuming they use SQL which they might not use. Your answer does not provide a way to do this via Doctrine but via PDO which does not answer OP's question. Also, OP might not even have such things as controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `PHP` >= `5.5`, which you should, you can always utilize [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function.

Just hydrate the result as `Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` and then run it through the function setting what column should be a key and what one should be a value:

```php
$result = $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
$keyVal = array_column($result, 'name', 'id');
```

The `$keyVal` variable contains the result set in the format you require.